How does a fight between Troubleshooters work in Paranoia New And Shiny (2023)?
In Paranoia The All New Shiny Edition, aka Perfect, aka 2023* there's no dodging. This makes me ask who rolls what in PC on PC combat.
Only way to avoid laser is to go before that traitorous bastard who is trying to shoot you**. So how do I assign the difficulty? I know, I know, it can be totally arbitrary, but I still need some baseline. I'd think that base difficulty of 1, adjusted by the environment and circumstances (hiding - harder, standing proud looking elsewhere - easier) and with armor would work well?
For a fistfight, it seems you should be able to defend yourself. I can't find a section about how this would work at all. If they go at the same initiative, I would be inclined to let them roll, and assign difference in successes as the wound to the poor guy who lost. Or, if both went full aggro, I'd give wounds to both.
Are there any rules I'm missing? And if not, are my ideas consistent with the overall feel of the game?

* It's Paranoia, have you expected consistency?!
** Or perceive and move faster than light, good luck with that.

"Lasers fire. Everybody dies."

I'm WJ, and I'm the lead designer behind Perfect Edition. Thanks for this question!
There are a few game-design reasons for no dodging in Paranoia:

Paranoia combat should be quick and deadly. Dodging attacks makes combat slower and safer. (Remember, everyone has multiple lives to mitigate the deadliness.)
We want to encourage players to spend Moxie on going faster. Losing it (running out of Moxie) is full of fun mayhem, and playtesting showed some fun competitiveness from spending that Moxie to go sooner.
This applies to firefights and fistfights for the same two reasons above. Remember, Paranoia is not about what's realistic but what's entertaining.

If you really want to, you could introduce a close combat dodge. Give that PC a DIFF, and they add 1 to the other person's DIFF for each success at or above the DIFF. However, I'd say they can only do this if they go before the incoming attack, and this takes up their turn. (Or just do what you want since it's your game now!)
Setting the DIFF does not have to be arbitrary! We recommend either 1) considering the in-game situation (ex: are they in a crowded room or empty room) or 2) whatever helps create paranoia and/or whatever gives players a reason to attack their own teammates.
For example, what if the Team Leader and the Loyalty Officer get into a laser fight? If they're doing this in a crowded transbot platform, I'd say DIFF 3 or 4 to avoid terminating an innocent bystander (because that gets them in trouble). If the Team Leader is needed for some reason, give DIFF 1 or 2 to the Loyalty Officer (because that creates more chaos). Does that make sense?
In other words, don't worry about what would be "realistic" or "possible". Focus on what makes the game more fun, chaotic, and deadly. This goes for every Paranoia rule and situation. And if you're ever unsure, just give them both DIFF 1 so they die off faster. :)
FYI, armour takes away successes from the opposing roll, so I wouldn't let that affect the DIFF.
Did I answer all your questions above?

This answer is good, but could be improved by some structure to clearly separate out the rules-based sections, the designer reasons sections, and the proposed houserules.
